# No close button in GNOME 3

Tags: gnome

Well, I have done a new ubuntu 11.04 installation and also added the gnome3-team ppa and installed gnome3, which is running now.

All is perfect, except one very annoying issue:

The windows I open, have no close button at all!

This is not the usual issue that new users have when they find that the maximize and minimize buttons are gone - in my case the close button is gone too, the window bar only has the title of the window in it, nothing else.

Nevertheless I have tried adding those buttons min/max buttons to the :close entry in gconf settings (using gconf-editor or gnome-tweak-tool). There were no changes, I still have no buttons whatsoever.

Something is obviously wrong, but can't figure out what.

Comment: Maybe using Gnome3 is wrong? :)...
All jokes aside, using the GNOME 3 PPA is unsupported and prone to major issues. I suggest waiting for, or switching to Ubuntu 11.10 (be prepared for bugs, but at least it will provide a proper GNOME 3 experience).

Comment: I agree with Roland. Hacking Gnome3 onto 11.04 is not a good idea.

Comment: I agree with you guys, living on the bleeding edge comes with problems :) But, this is only a minor issue - I find that everything else is very stable and working perfectly. Switching to ubuntu 11.11 before beta1 would be probably a worse idea :>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use the Gnome3 session or the Gnome classic? 
Do you use compiz or metacity as window panel?
When I start to use gnome 3, I was the same problem.
Try to install the Compiz fusion icon first. 
Select your windows manager, choose Metacity.
Reload Windows manager.
I wish it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much @amixr ! It must be a compiz-decorator bug. As soon as I change to metacity the buttons appear again! Looking into it now to see if there's a bug report or something. Btw I have no 'gnome3-session' when on gdm, don't know why. I use the 'ubuntu-classic' session and load gnome-shell

Comment: Ok, I don't know what's going on with compiz, but I found an even better solution. I'm using mutter (apt-get install mutter) and set that up as the default window manager. It is the metacity extension with compositing, it's going to be default on gnome3 anyway. No need for compiz, mutter is just as fun :)

Comment: To change the window manager of preference the user can change the following gconf key: /desktop/gnome/applications/window_manager/default